# Python - PCRE_NOTEMPTY

Tags: python, regex

This is a very basic question, but I am stuck, so any help would be appreciated.

```
import re
re.split(r'(\d|\W|\_)', '  ab2c d_ef')
['', ' ', '', ' ', 'ab', '2', 'c', ' ', 'd', '_', 'ef']
```

How do I get rid of the empty '' match? I do need the space character. I want my output to look like below:

```
[' ', ' ', 'ab', '2', 'c', ' ', 'd', '_', 'ef']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of `re.split`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[a-z]+|\d+|_|\s', '  ab2c d_ef')
[' ', ' ', 'ab', '2', 'c', ' ', 'd', '_', 'ef']
```

You don't need to escape `_`. It does not have special meaning in regular expression.